# Tensorflow: How can I run tensorflow job repeatedly?

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to run `tensorflow` deep learning program repeatedly with different hyperparameters.

```
for i in range(10):
    my_learner = DQNLearner()
    my_learner.build_network()
    my_learner.run()


class DQNLearner():
    def build_network(self):
        W1 = tf.get_variable(
            "W1",
            shape=[self.input_size, h_size],
            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        )
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_size]))
        L1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self._X, W1) + b1)
        L1 = tf.nn.dropout(L1, keep_prob=self.keep_prob)

        W2 = tf.get_variable(
            "W2",
            shape=[h_size, h_size],
            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
        )
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_size]))
        L2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(L1, W2) + b2)
        L2 = tf.nn.dropout(L2, keep_prob=self.keep_prob)
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

It works well in first loop. But in 2nd loop, it occurs like this:

```
ValueError: Variable W1 already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.get_variable` method tries to give you an existing variable if it has been already called, otherwise it will create a new one. See [the variable guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables)

What you could do is to reset the graph between two loops by calling `tf.reset_default_graph()`. By doing so, the new variables will be added to a fresh new default graph :

```
for i in range(10):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    my_learner = DQNLearner()
    my_learner.build_network()
    my_learner.run()
```

Another way would be to keep your variables and to reinitialise them between two loops using the initialiser op. For example you could do:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
my_learner = DQNLearner()
my_learner.build_network()

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
for i in range(10):
    sess.run(init_op)
    my_learner.run()
```